# std::vector push_back with std::move still copies object

Tags: c++

I have a base class called Socket, then subclass called RwSocket, and a subclass to that called RoSocket.

I push_back into a std::vector the instances of the two subclasses, and see the copy constructor getting invoked. However when I push either one only, then no copy constructor is invoked, only move constructor. I never want the copy constructor to get invoked.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


class SocketInterface
{
  public:
  SocketInterface(const std::string &name)
   : m_name(name)
  {
    cout << m_name << " ctor" << this << endl;
  }
  SocketInterface(const std::string &&name)
     : m_name(std::move(name))
  {
    cout << m_name << " ctor2" << this << endl;
  }
  virtual ~SocketInterface()
  {
    cout << m_name << " dtor" <<  this << endl;
  }
  SocketInterface(const SocketInterface&rhs)
     : m_name(rhs.m_name)
  {
     cout << m_name << " cptor&" <<  this << endl;
  }
  SocketInterface(const SocketInterface&&rhs)
     : m_name(std::move(rhs.m_name))
  {
     cout << m_name << " mvtor&&" <<  this << endl;
  }
  virtual void write(const std::string&) const = 0;
  virtual std::string read() const = 0;

  protected:
  std::string m_name;
};

class RwSocket : public SocketInterface
{
  public:
  RwSocket(const std::string &name)
  : SocketInterface(name) {}
  virtual ~RwSocket() {}
  RwSocket(const RwSocket&rhs)
     : SocketInterface(rhs)
  {}
  RwSocket(const RwSocket&&rhs)
     : SocketInterface(std::move(rhs))
  {}

  virtual void write(const std::string &message) const override
  {
    cout << m_name << " " << this << " " << message << endl;
  }
  virtual std::string read() const override
  {
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::hex << this;
    auto self = ss.str();
    return m_name + " " + self + " did read something";
  }
};

class RoSocket : public RwSocket
{
  public:
   RoSocket(const std::string &name)
   : RwSocket(name)
   {}
   virtual ~RoSocket() {}
   RoSocket(RoSocket&rhs)
      : RwSocket(rhs)
   {}
   RoSocket(const RoSocket&&rhs)
      : RwSocket(std::move(rhs))
   {}

  virtual void write(const std::string &message) const override
  {
  }

  virtual std::string read() const override
  {
    return RwSocket::read();
  }

};

void work(std::vector<RwSocket> &&sockets)
{
  for(auto&& socket : sockets)
  {
    socket.write("writing outgoing message");
    cout << socket.read() << endl;
  }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   std::vector<RwSocket> sockets;
   sockets.emplace_back(std::move(RoSocket("ro")));
   sockets.emplace_back(std::move(RwSocket("rw")));
   work(std::move(sockets));
   return;
}
```

Output:

```
ro ctor0x7fff9752a120
ro mvtor&&0x1f8c590
ro dtor0x7fff9752a120
rw ctor0x7fff9752a180
rw mvtor&&0x1fa2bb8
ro cptor&0x1fa2b90
ro dtor0x1f8c590
rw dtor0x7fff9752a180
ro 0x1fa2b90 writing outgoing message
ro 0x1fa2b90 did read something
rw 0x1fa2bb8 writing outgoing message
rw 0x1fa2bb8 did read something
ro dtor0x1fa2b90
rw dtor0x1fa2bb8
```

But when I comment out either one of these

```
   sockets.emplace_back(std::move(RoSocket("ro")));
   sockets.emplace_back(std::move(RwSocket("rw")));
```

then the copy constructor does not get invoked.

Why is the copy constructor getting called if I push more than once?

Comment: You want nothrow-movable objects in a vector.

Comment: with `std::vector<RwSocket>`, you have slicing with `sockets.emplace_back(std::move(RoSocket("ro")))`.

Comment: `RoSocket("ro")` is already a rvalue, no need to move it.

Comment: Thanks, this is a duplicate indeed. Answer was to use noexcept qualifier in the move constructors.